# How to run a command from python library?

Tags: python, macos

I downloaded a python library but am unable to use the commands within it. I made a script which consists of the following:

```
   import pyModeS as pms
   pms.modeslive()
```

where "modeslive" is one of the commands from the library. Executing this script results in `module has no attribute "modeslive"`. If you look at the documentation (https://github.com/junzis/pyModeS) that is similar to how they suggest using it. What am I doing wrong and where can I learn more about this?

Comment: I think it's explained quite well in the docs: https://github.com/junzis/pyModeS

Comment: to me it seems that "modeslive --source rtlsdr" can be used directly from terminal, while in the python script you cannot use modeslive()

Answer (score 3):

#### you can try this:

```
import pyModeS
pyModeS.command()
```

or

```
from pyModeS import command
command()
```

#### example with time library:

```
import time
time.sleep(2)
```

or

```
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
```

Comment: Also make sure that your file doesn't have the same name as the library you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

As @gegkigek99 mentioned, modeslive is an executable file run from command line / terminal. Navigating to the folder that modeslive was in and executing it as a python script solved the problem.